# How to know which type of brush is ID2D1Brush?

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, directx, direct2d

I have a [ID2D1Brush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) previously created by using [CreateSolidColorBrush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371867(v=vs.85).aspx) or [CreateLinearGradientBrush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742783(v=vs.85).aspx).

I need to know if my pointer is a `ID2D1SolidColorBrush` or a `ID2D1LinearGradientBrush`. How can I do?

```
ID2D1Brush* brush = ...

if (brush is ID2D1SolidColorBrush)
{
}
else if (brush is ID2D1LinearGradientBrush)
{
}
```

Comment: `QueryInterface` for `ID2D1SolidColorBrush`?

Comment: @RomanR. I already use QueryInterface but it does not return any error if, for example, I have a solid color brush and I query for a linear gradient brush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querying will only suffer if you choose to do this on each render pass, and may be exactly what you need.

```
ID2D1Brush* brush = nullptr;
// ...

ID2D1LinearGradientBrush *linearGradientBrush = nullptr;
if (S_OK == brush->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID2D1LinearGradientBrush), (void**)&linearGradientBrush))
{
    // ...
}
```

I use this strategy where a base class will hold a given resource (such as a background brush) and allow the user (or developer) to set this to their preference.  In this case (with the linear gradient brush, clamping is necessary.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In `C++` you track stuff yourself. This is not `C#`. So there are two cases:

- Your resources are static and you know each thing what is so you don't query at runtime.
- You use a wrapper class around the `ID2D1SolidColorBrush` where you store further information about the brush. Using an `enum` of brush types meaningful for your app.

Querying is a poor choice vs. tracking yourself in terms of performance.

Comment: It would seem a poor solution.

Comment: @Nick I think it's either the `QuerryInterface()`  which is some run-time overhead, or the wrapper which is some coding overhead.  For a graphic engine, I'd opt for the second.